# How to identify unique clients in Rails or with a preferred Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to figure out how to identify unique users properly with cookies and perhaps coupling that with the public IP.

What's the suggested path to follow in this regard? (I'm open to a standard Rails method or leveraging another Ruby Gem if that's more elegant.)

On the topic of cookies, which is the proper way to retrieve client cookies in Rails 3.x+? I have been using `cookies`, but it seems that `request.cookies` also works. *What is the difference / preference when using these two?*  I've seemingly seen `request.cookies` fail in some instances; but perhaps it was after clearing out the cookies for the app prior to refreshing and working with it in the console.

*Also, do cookies have a unique ID that can be utilized to identify clients uniquely?*

Essentially my goal is to count visits per unique visitor to a site.  I am assuming I will need to compare a unique cookie ID and perhaps an IP, but I'm not sure what would be most kosher in this situation.

Ultimately I need to to understand how to uniquely identify visitors of the site and then store them in a count or number of visits to the site for that visitor.

Comment: The only person who sets cookies for your site is you, so the question of "do cookies have a unique ID" is really on you...

Comment: Okay so @MarcTalbot, that's what I was curious about. I wasn't seeing a default id of any kind, but it seemed as though perhaps that might be within the realm of default function.  Apparently not!  So that's helpful, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with cookies in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862864/working-with-cookies-in-rails) by the same user.

Comment: Absolutely is @AndrewMarshall. Since it received such negative remarks and downvoting, I figured that that question is indeed a dud and will need to be deleting it here when the system permits.  As you can see on examination, this is not a duplicate, but reworded and reworked with care so as to remove any doubts of value, so I'd appreciate if you could please not vote to close the item since I sincerely am looking for some input here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question on the difference between `cookies` and `request.cookies` see 
http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails#scvr

It's well explained.